# How to test dummy credit card details in PayPal?

Tags: testing, paypal, woocommerce, payment

I'm setting up a WooCommerce website and I'm testing PayPal payments. I've tried the numbers on here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

I'm trying to test payment with a credit card without having a PayPal account, but doing it through PayPal's system.

Problem is, the list only includes card numbers, but the payment requires a CVV, correct address/location/country etc. and phone number. I've tried putting in random information for the rest but it throws and error, saying that its invalid.

Thankyou for any help in advance.

Comment: register a paypal account then go to https://developer.paypal.com/ and you get a sandbox account there with card details to test with

Comment: Ah thanks man. I found it when I logged into sandbox.paypal.com and went to the profile settings.